# how can solve " phased array toolbox "

Tags: matlab

As I read it need to add a package.
I don't know to solve this problem.
the problem in

```
bb=rotz(hi(i));
```

To use 'rotz', you might need:
  rotz - Phased Array System Toolbox

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply make your own version of the function if you don't have the required toolbox.  [`rotz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/rotz.html) is simply a rotation matrix rotating around the `z` axis.  It accepts an angle **in degrees** and returns a 3 x 3 matrix.  Recall that the rotation matrix around the `x`, `y` and `z` axes are:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)</sup>

Therefore, you can define `rotz` to be:

```
function M = rotz(ang)
    M = [cosd(ang) -sind(ang) 0; sind(ang) cosd(ang) 0; 0 0 1]; 
end
```

Save this code in a file called `rotz.m` where you intend to run your main code and use it.  Note that we're using [`cosd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cosd.html) and [`sind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sind.html) take in **degrees** as the input and not radians (via `cos` and `sin`).